# JBPM Community Edition feature availability

Tags: redhat, jbpm

we are evaluating JBPM and would like to understand if following is support is available with community edition

1. Model validation      :  does it validate against the whole process and identify issues such cycle loops or dead locks?
2. Adaptive/ Event based dynamicity support: As events occur, a person or system chooses the appropriate activity. The resulting steps can vary depending on the event and choices made by the worker. Activities are not directly linked to one another.
3. Multi lingual support: which langauges supported
4. Workflow load predictions  based on historical data?
5. Process related
   Process simulation Support
   Process Optimization Support
   Dynamic Process Support
6. Supporting failure recovery  : After failure, once restarted, the engine reprocesses all pending events, after having recovered its last stable internal state.
7. HIGH Availability based clustering Production deployment support
8. Availability of Production Support for community edition deployment (on chargeable/ subscription)
9. Availability of Commercial Remote & On-Site Training. (on chargeable/ subscription)

Answer (score 0):

Please find the response inline (AFAIK).

> Model validation: does it validate against the whole process and identify issues such cycle loops or dead locks?

There is an option to validate for every type of asset in jBPM which covers various scenarios and provides warnings and error messages.

> Adaptive/ Event based dynamicity support: As events occur, a person or system chooses the appropriate activity. The resulting steps can vary depending on the event and choices made by the worker. Activities are not directly linked to one another.

Event-based gateways allow reacting to possible Events and

> Multilingual support: which langauges supported

Not sure.

> Workflow load predictions based on historical data?

Not Sure

> Process related Process simulation Support Process Optimization Support Dynamic Process Support
>
> Supporting failure recovery : After failure, once restarted, the engine reprocesses all pending events, after having recovered its last stable internal state.

Yes, jBPM persists internal states and runtime details of the process in DB (Default is H2 DB), refer [Documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/jbpm/release/7.36.0.Final/jbpm-docs/html_single/#_jbpmpersistence)  to learn more about it.

> HIGH Availability based clustering Production deployment support

Refer [Link](https://docs.jboss.org/jbpm/release/7.36.0.Final/jbpm-docs/html_single/#_wb.workbenchhighavailability) for configuring business-central high availability.

> Availability of Production Support for community edition deployment (on chargeable/ subscription)

Subscription-based support is available for  Red Hat Process Automation Manager not for community edition. You can check with RedHat sales for more details.

> Availability of Commercial Remote & On-Site Training. (on chargeable/ subscription)

Red Hat does provide various training courses for the RedHat process automation manager.